# brokeredMessage.GetBody<ClassName>() throws error in the receiver

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus

I am using the Example 5 from below article for creating/sending brokered message from a different application/solution than the receiver. But, it still throws below error in different scenarios:

https://abhishekrlal.com/2012/03/30/formatting-the-content-for-service-bus-messages/

1. When I provide [DataContract(Namespace = "NamespaceName")] as in the example while creating brokered message.

{"Expecting element 'ClassName' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NamespaceName'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'ClassName', namespace 'NamespaceName'. "}

2. When I provide [DataContract(Namespace = "")] as in the example while creating brokered message.

"Expecting element 'ClassName' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NamespaceName'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'ClassName', namespace ''. "}

Comment: @Mikhail - any ideas about the above. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759627/unknown-xml-serialization-content-namespace-from-service-bus-brokered-message

Comment: @Rob Reagan - just tagging since I have seen similar question answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420248/azure-service-bus-brokered-message-getbody-deserialization

Comment: `I am using the Example 5 from below article for creating/sending brokered message from a different application/solution than the receiver` What kind  of application to send and receive the brokered message? Have you referenced to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427361/azure-service-bus-read-messages-sent-by-net-core-2-with-brokeredmessage-getbo/47431262#47431262)?

Comment: I am using a console .net application to send brokered message. And, web jobs functions to receive brokered message.

Comment: I use the [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) SDK on my side, and it works correctly on my side.

Comment: Hi Vicky, what version of the SDK are you using? Also, can you post code for your serialization? You may have copied and pasted the code from example 5, but I'd love to see more context.